# extension function on List for elements compliant to multiple interfaces

Tags: kotlin, generics

The following code creates an extension function for `List` that contain elements that are implementing the `InterfaceCustomFirebaseData`.

```
fun List<InterfaceCustomFirebaseData>.toFirebaseDate(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val firebaseData: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
    this.forEach { firebaseData[it.id] = it.toFirebaseData() }
    return firebaseData
}
```

But I need the `List` elements to be compliant to **2** interfaces (`InterfaceCustomFirebaseData` and also `InterfaceIdentifiable`), but this does not work:

```
fun List<InterfaceCustomFirebaseData, InterfaceIdentifiable>.toFirebaseDate(): MutableMap<String, Any> { ... }
```

The compiler gives error "*One type argument expected for interface List*"

How should this be written in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself:

```
fun <T> List<T>.toFirebaseDate(): MutableMap<String, Any> where T : InterfaceCustomFirebaseData, T : InterfaceIdentifiable {
    val firebaseData: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
    this.forEach { firebaseData[it.id] = it.toFirebaseData() }
    return firebaseData
}
```